# Migrate two different models from two different Django applications

Tags: python, django, django-models, makemigrations

Hi guys so i have a Django project with two application named, shopper, parcel, each of this app have one model also named Parcel and Shopper. there is a one-to-many relationship between the 2 models. the problem is i want to migrate the two models, if I was just one i could have gone with the normal way of migrating a model.
This is what i have tried

```
python manage.py makemigrations parcel
python manage.py migrate
```

the problem with the first one is it does not take the other models in the shopper app into consideration and that is not what i want.

```
python manage.py makemigrations parcel
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations shopper
python manage.py migrate
```

this was my second solution, the commands end up creating migration of each model but still i don't think that is the right thing to do.
Any help in the right direction please

Comment: I would avise to give the models different names. Having models with the same name in two apps will only result in a lot of confusion, not only for migrations, but for queries, forms, views, etc.

Comment: okay will take that into consideration